# poloniex api error: invalid command

Tags: javascript

Having issues returning chart data from poloniex api, the reloadData() just returns successfully with an error, error: "Invalid command." .

https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=14400

This link shows the data i'm trying to get but it fails in javaScript with the same arguments?

API info https://poloniex.com/support/api/

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
window.onload = function() {
  reloadData();
}

function reloadData() {

  $.ajax({ // fetch some chart data
    url: 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=14400',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: It works fine for me too !

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function reloadData() {         
              $.ajax({ // fetch some chart data
                url: 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=14400',
                success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
                }
              });
            }   
            window.onload = function() {
              reloadData();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```